# Unknown Message in LogCat

Tags: android, logcat, android-logcat

I got a Unknown message in LogCat

[COMP] OVL Might be hangQQ Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071).

Does any body knows what it means

LogCat Output

```
10-01 12:32:49.247: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:49.607: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:49.967: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:50.327: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:50.687: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:51.047: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:51.407: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:51.767: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:52.127: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:52.487: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:52.847: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:53.207: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:53.567: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:53.927: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:54.287: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
10-01 12:32:54.647: E/hwcomposer(129): [COMP] OVL might be hang!! Fence index blocks at (2070) and last (2071)
```

Comment: *HWcomposer enables UserInterface (UI) rendering via GPU*

Comment: you dont have to worry about this message, you might have `Verbose` Setting for Logcat

Answer (score 0):

So i get this messages when start App on real device, than restart Studio, replug device with turned off screen and find out this messages. When i open app on pluged in device this messages stops.